# Kitchen faucet causing spike in water pressure

Tags: plumbing, faucet, water-pressure

today I bought a pressure gage to check my water pressure.  Put it on and it is sitting at 70 PSI. Left it on for an hour and saw it had spiked to 100. Reset the red needle and had my wife flush toliets and turn on/off faucets and showers. What I found out is that the pressure only spikes when our kitchen faucet is turned on or off. Did it with cold water only. Anybody heard of this? Any repair or just install a new one? Also 70 psi reading seems a bit high. I don't know if I have a PRV or where it might be. Can I just close the water supply a bit at the street to decrease water pressure? Thanks for your input.

Edit 1 Adding further detail:
The black needle quickly goes up to 100 and the red needle stays there and the black needle quickly returns. Both with turning on and off. The main shut off is at the street and we live up on a hill from there, so never been able to find shut off at house just at the street. Tks

Comment: Imagine the kitchen faucet is turning off fast spiking the pressure for a second.  Does the gauge read pressure or read the max and stay there?  70 pounds is the upper side of okay, start getting above 80 gets iffy.   A PRV should be near where the water comes into the house(just after main valve).

Comment: 70 psi is way way to high. You pressure regulator is set wrong or not working

Comment: do you know where the water comes in the home? Do you know how pressure regulator looks like ? it could be inside or outside your home

Comment: Did you buy the pressure gauge due to **actual problems you've left out of your question** or on a whim? I'm assuming the latter until you update.  You also need to visit this page to correct the "two different accounts" problem which is why you can't comment and edit your own post: https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Most households have an inlet water pressure of **40-45 PSI**

Comment: Are you close to a water pumping station perhaps? It would also help to know what country you are in.  In NZ the minimum is supposed to be 25+.  In USA (supposedly) 40-45.  From my Googling.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a bit of "water hammer" from operating the valve quickly. If you operate the valve **deliberately slowly**, that almost certainly will eliminate the spike in pressure, which is just from the sudden stoppage of the water flowing to the kitchen sink. That may have a valve of a type that shuts off particularly fast, or it may be because of where the pressure gauge is located on your system relative to that line, or both.

If you don't hear water hammer, (*i.e.* pipe noises when you shut off the kitchen sink) you can either ignore it, or add a **water hammer arrestor** to the kitchen sink line. Replacing the faucet is not indicated, unless you want to for other reasons.

70 PSI is within the typical acceptable range for delivered water pressure. Above 80 various things (toilet fill valves most typically) get iffy. It's not an uncommon level for town/city pressure.

Partially closing a valve will have no effect on static pressure (the 70 PSI you measure) but it will restrict the flow and cause (generally an undesirable amount of) pressure loss when water is flowing. Not a solution to your perceived problem, if it's a problem at all.

Comment: Most households have an inlet water pressure of **40-45** PSI

Comment: IPC 604.8 - a pressure reducing valve is required only when the static pressure supplied exceeds 80 PSI.

Comment: that is cutting it close to damage

Answer (score 1):

Most households have an inlet water pressure of **40-45 PSI**

Your **70 PSI** is on high end, and above 80 is not recomended.

You need to find the water pressure regulator and lower the pressure.

A regulator can fail and may need to be replaced. It is usually found where the water main enters the home, right after the main shut off valve. The other shut-off valve is on the street, just before water meter.

Partially closing the main valve will not reduce the pressure, but it will reduce water flow.

FYI, devices like the water dispensing Fridge, require or have built in pressure regulators reducing the pressure to 35 PSI, because they use plastic hoses inside.

Comment: I would like to add that the OP should also ensure that the fridge has a pressure regulator or pressure reducing valve.